# Convert rectangle to polygon with addRectangle

Tags: java, polygon, rectangles

How do I use the following method to convert a rectangle into a polygon?

```
public void addRectangle(int xPos, int yPos, int dX, int dY)
```

I have already tried:

```
/** * Converts the rectangle supplied into a polygon by making a new polygon 
and adding each of the rectangle's corners as points. */

public static Polygon RectangleToPolygon(Rectangle rect) {
   Polygon result = new Polygon(); 
   result.addPoint(rect.x, rect.y); 
   result.addPoint(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y); 
   result.addPoint(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height); 
   result.addPoint(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height);
   return result; 
}
```

Comment: Can you use Area instead of Polygon? It's a snap to do this with Area

Comment: Where is that `addRectangle` method from? Do you have it or are you supposed to write it? And What happened when you tried the code? What was wrong?

Comment: i am supposed to write it. using this method to convert a rectangle to polygon and add it to an array list

Answer (score 1):

Better use the constructor with all data.

```
public static Polygon RectangleToPolygon(Rectangle rect) {
    int[] xpoints = {rect.x, rect.x + rect.width, rect.x + rect.width, rect.x}:
    int[] ypoints = {rect.y, rect.y, rect.y + rect.height, rect.y + rect.height};
    return new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, 4); 
}
```

Or substitute rect's x, y, widht, height with

```
int xPos, int yPos, int dX, int dY
```